# VMware Tools installed but not working on Kali Linux

Tags: vmware-workstation, kali-linux

I've successfully installed VMwareTools-10.0.5-3228253.tar.gz on Kali Linux rolling release 2016.1.

1. I extracted it onto the desktop in a new folder
2. I opened the folder
3. I opened terminal in that folder and wrote:

   ```
   ./vmware-install.pl
   ```

   4. I followed the installation steps until it finished
   5. It told me that the tools installed successfully
   6. I restarted the VM

After I had restarted the VM, I found that VMware Tools didn't work. I am now unable to copy/paste anything between my Windows 10 host and my Kali Linux guest on VMware Workstation 12.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  How is each set up; how are you trying to share files; what, precisely, works and doesn't work; and what are the symptoms when it doesn't work?

Comment: I cannot copy or share files between kali linux and my windows although I followed the installation steps and it told me that tools installed succefully but when I tryed copy files from windows to kali it didnot work

Comment: This really just repeats what's in your question.  Without the details of exactly what you set up and how you're trying to do it, people can only guess at what the problem might be.

Comment: @fixer1234 do you understand now ?

Comment: One purpose of a VM is to isolate the guest from the host.  You aren't supposed to be able to freely copy and paste anywhere unless you provide for that.  You don't mention anything about configuring your virtual machine settings to enable shared folders or specifying which directories on your system are to be shared.  You don't mention whether you're sharing or mirroring folders.  If you haven't configured that, it's working the way it's supposed to by not letting you copy and paste across the boundary.  The VMware tools just help do some things and improve behavior after the setup is done.

Comment: @fixer1234 How can I configure that ?

Comment: I used VMware only once, years ago, so I'm rusty on the exact steps.  But if you google, "vmware share files" there's a ton of tutorials.

Comment: Ok thanks for help @fixer1234 I will search for it

Answer (score 1):

In Kali Linux 2016 you have to install `open-vm-tools` instead of `vmware-guest-tools`.

To have drag and drop, copy and paste and screen resolution working correctly you need to follow these steps:

1. Add the Kali 2016 repositories to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
   ```
2. Run these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse
   reboot
   ```