# VMware 'Drag&Drop' feature stopped working with Kali

Tags: kali-linux, vmware-workstation

I am using a Windows 10 host machine with a VMware Workstation 15 Pro (15.0.2 build-10952284).

The drag&drop feature stopped working with one of the guest machines, which is a Kali Linux (Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 2020.3). It still works fine for the windows machines.

The copy&paste feature works fine for all machines, Kali included.

So far I have tried:

- Restarting the guest, VMware, and the host machine
- Checking the guest isolation options, which are properly checked.
- Reinstalling the VMware tools as instructed by the feature "Reinstall VMware Tools..." - This broke the c&p feature.
- Follow the steps to install open-vm-tools from a similar problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1063477/vmware-tools-installed-but-not-working-on-kali-linux) - This caused the machine to freeze completely whenever I tried to drag&drop.
- Tried some similar solution with slight variations [here](https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-vmware-tools-kali-guest/) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691585/copy-paste-and-dragdrop-not-working-in-vmware-machine-with-ubuntu) - Same result
- Check and uncheck the guest isolation as also suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691585/copy-paste-and-dragdrop-not-working-in-vmware-machine-with-ubuntu) - Did nothing
- Enable the `run-vmblock\\x2dfuse.mount` feature as suggested [here](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/319) - Also nothing
- Update: Also used this excellent [guide](https://vinaysit.com/2019/10/16/copy-paste-and-drag-n-drop-between-windows-and-vmware-workstation-debian-ubuntu-vm/), which is somewhat similar to the above, but uses the `--purge` options when removing the previous package. This solved the freeze issue, but did not enable the DnD feature.

If anyone has any solution for this I would highly appreciate it :-)

Would be happy to provide any further details necessary.

Thanks!

**Update:**
The guest is bridged to the host's network, but for some reason I can only ping host->guest and not the other way around. When I turn off the firewall I can ping both ways, but not drag and drop.

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop in this context is for files.

Is your other system properly mapped (smb://192.168.x.y) ?

If I map a drive on the other system, drag and drop works fine. If I do not map a drive, drag and drop does not work.  So this is likely a security change.

Without logging in, the feature will depend upon successful browsing which does not always work, even now in Windows. So it is necessary to map a drive before dragging and dropping.

**Follow up note:**

> I am using a Windows 10 host machine with a VMware Workstation 15 Pro
> (15.0.2 build-10952284).

There was an issue with Kali machines and a VMware Workstation 15 + version causing Kali to hang and VMware to "Stop Working"  Nothing to do with Drag and Drop. But it was corrected in Workstation 15 ++ .  Try upgrading VMware Workstation. I am using V16 at this point.

**In response to the Firewall question:**

> The following ports are associated with file sharing and server
> message block (SMB) communications: Microsoft file sharing SMB: User
> Datagram Protocol (UDP) ports from 135 through 139 and Transmission
> Control Protocol (TCP) ports from 135 through 139.

From:  [https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/298804/internet-firewalls-can-prevent-browsing-and-file-sharing#:~:text=The%20following%20ports%20are%20associated,ports%20from%20135%20through%20139](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/298804/internet-firewalls-can-prevent-browsing-and-file-sharing#:%7E:text=The%20following%20ports%20are%20associated,ports%20from%20135%20through%20139).

Also make sure File and Print Sharing and Network Discovery or the equivalent for Linux are enabled on all machines.

Comment: Do you mean if I have a shared folder with the guest?

Comment: Yes. You need to be able to see the folder in the other machine.  So make sure the Kali machine can see the folder / file you are trying to drag / drop.

Comment: I amended my answer to cover browsing which is not reliable like it used to be in less secured systems. This is true even in Windows.

Comment: Ok, I have successfully mounted a shared folder (using the link at the end), and can now transfer files using it. Drag and drop still causes freeze in the guest Kali. Link: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html

Comment: Try doing all updates to Kali and I also have Kernel at V5.7.  I have two Kali V2020.3 machines on two different hosts and neither one freezes doing drag and drop.

Comment: Also consider upgrading VMware Workstation. You should be able to gt to V15.5 for free and V16 for a small fee if your are outside of one year of your purchase.

Comment: I have updated all of Kali packages, drag and drop still causes freeze... But the shared folder is working, which is also helpful. I will consider purchasing VMware 16. Update: I think it has to do with the firewall, I have added an update to the question

Comment: I amended my answer with information of firewalls and file sharing.

Comment: Tried everything, somewhere during the updates it stopped freezing, but I can't get drag and drop even when the firewall is off now. It looks like a security issue, but I can't seem to find the relevant settings...

Comment: Browsing is not very secure so that may be this issue with drag and drop.